# How to print each report on one page in RDLC report?

Tags: sql, rdlc

I am making a RDLC report. which has tablix , charts and all..other stuff..

I need to ask one thing that , how can I make report that each chart or tablix or rectangle comes on a Single page.

Eagerly waiting for the reply.

Thanks,

Nitin

Answer (score 0):

> I believe if you set the report's interactive height to 0 this will will put the entire report on one page.

[Original Article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5733e039-7031-454a-b9ad-981a93d97f1f/fit-data-on-one-page?forum=sqlreportingservices)